# Expectation of a matrix of random variables

Tags: probability, matrices, probability-theory, random-variables, random-matrices

Let $A_{ij}$ be a collection of $N^2$ random variables where $i,j\in\{1,\dots,N\}$. Let $f(A_{ij})$ denote the joint probability distribution of random variables $A_{ij}$. How do we define the "expected matrix" for this?. For instance, for a scalar random variable $x$ with pdf as $f(x)$, one has the usual definition of expectation as $\int xf(x)dx$. How do we define such a notion for matrices?

Comment: As usual, when you are working with random vector you take an entry-wise expectation - each entry is a univariate random variable and you know the definition of expectation of each of them. So the expectation is a vector. For random matrix it is the same generalization, the expectation is a matrix containing the expectations of each individual entries in the corresponding position.